# how to updateand detect the checked check boxes using default model table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, defaulttablemodel

I just wanna ask, how to detect a checked box on check boxes and how to update the table or delete the row of the checked box? i run this code and it exits the loop and didn't enter the if else statement :(

```
for(int i =table.getRowCount(); i>= 0 ; i++)
{
    a = (String)table.getModel().getValueAt(i,1);
    boolean getBool = (boolean)table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 6);
    if(getBool)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,getBool); 
        String sql2 = "UPDATE room_record SET Book_status = 'Checked_In' WHERE
        Room_Record_ID = '" + a + "'";
        statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
        statement.executeUpdate(sql2);
        ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(i)
        //model2.fireTableDataChanged();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"done"); 
        //System.out.println("true");
    }

}
```

Comment: show your code.  It's hard for us to answer that way.

Comment: i've showed my code edy~~ @La-comadreja

Answer (score 2):

> how to detect a checked box

Create a loop to read through the TableModel. Then use:

```
if (model.getValueAt(...).equals(Boolean.TRUE))
    // do something
```

> delete the row of the checked box?

Use the `removeRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel`

Note when you loop through the TableModel you will need to start with the last entry and decrement your index by 1 until you get to 0 so the removeRow() method will work on the proper row.

Edit:

Did you add a System.out.println(...) statement inside your loop to make sure the code was executing? This is a simple debugging technique to test your logic. Your code won't execute because your looping structure in incorrect.

```
int i =table.getRowCount();
```

You can't start at the row count because Java starts offsets at zero so you need to use:

```
int i =table.getRowCount() - 1;
```

I then suggested you need to `decrement` the index. Why are you using:

```
i++
```

That does an increment, not a decrement.

Comment: i tried but i couldn't D: i updated my code edy up there.. sorry i dont know how to use this.. i'm new since yesterday :O